# Any way to freeze a window / application?

Tags: python

Example of what I wish to happen:

I have a game open which I am current holding left click down into, I want the ability to minimize or go to another window without taking away that sent input of holding down left click to that application. I have tried VM's and none of that seems to work very well.

I would prefer to find a way to do this in Python. However, if there is a solution in any other language I will happily accept that as well, anything works.

Comment: very interesting question. What have you tried so far

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I havent done much, as I have no idea how to do something like this. All I have tried is using vm's to achieve the same thing but most of them don't run games / need a gpu pass through, and its all things I'd rather save as my last resort if I cam just do it this way.